# Set view as a top view Cocoa OSX

Tags: cocoa, nsview, mousedown

I have some views on the window, of which I am concerned about two views and among them one is the root view. I am adding the other as a subview in the init method of the super view. After that some views are being added and are overlapped on my subview. The problem is how to get my subview top of all other subviews to the rootview till required and how to prevent otherviews from taking down the mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSView addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]` (as per the [NSView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCCFEBE)).